# CuBase LE 5 Static Noises

Tags: audio-recording, daw, cubase, noise

I bought a Lexicon Lambda interface and connected it to my MacBook Pro late 2011.

Specs:

Intel core i5 2.4GHz
16GB Ram
512GB SSD
OSX 10.9
Lexicon Lambda (Connected via USB to computer)
Samson Graphite 49 (Connected via USB to computer)

I installed CuBase LE 5 and then tried recording a sound with my microphone.
When I plug in the microphone to any of the inputs on the card I get terrible static noises even before playback or record... Just by pressing monitor... Same with the graphite controller, when I play on it the notes are distorted...

What I tried to do:

Restart the system
Install a patch from Steinberg's site
Use another cable
Use another USB port
Disconnect everything and try only with the interface
Trying every sample rate that CuBase showed me
Trying Mono and Stereo
Different volume and monitor levels on the interface
Different sockets on the interface

And then... I tried GarageBand... Which worked perfectly fine so what's the problem with CuBase why do I get static noises when I use it?

**EDIT:**
So Cubase 7 elements works perfect... And GarageBand as well
Reaper fails to work as well and Studio one 2 seems to dislike my audio interface...

I'm confused now...

Could it be because of Mavericks? I mean, Cubase 5 LE is old... And they didn't make any patches as far as I know...

Comment: At first I thought it was only when recording... But now I see that even if I don't connect anything to any jack in my interface it still makes static noises in cubase only... GarageBand records and works perfectly...

Comment: For reference, Odinn posted this question on Music.SE as well: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14254/cubase-le-5-static-noises-with-everything (I think this question is a better fit here at AVP.)

Comment: Any chance Cubase is *also* monitoring another source, such as a built-in computer mic?

Comment: how do I check it? in the devices I have an option to select only one.

Comment: Is your PC quick enough to handle C5? On my PC (very old), when I have a few tracks recorded with effects I begin to notice things happening when recording mic or guitar.

Comment: Yes, you can see the specs of my mac in my question...

Comment: Have you tried getting in touch with CuBase's tech support? If you have, or decide to do so, and get a good answer, please post it here so others with the same problem can learn from it. =)

Comment: http://www.steinberg.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=52515#p320608 - But I got nothing there... I can't use support because of the version.. LE

Comment: CuBase 7 Elements works fine though... Maybe it's because CuBase 5 is old and running it on OSX 10.9 cause some compatibility issues... IDK....

Answer (score 1):

You have a decent mac ... 16gigs.. 512 SSD... Why'd you go cheap on the interface? Those  lexicon usb interfaces are horrible.... really any usb interface in all honesty IMO..

I would say the unit itself is flawed and having grounding issues in the physical wiring inside the lexicon, but since you say its only in cubase 5 I'm gonna assume you got your Cubase 5 off of a torrent site.

I had a torrent version of Cubase 5 that had some very unique problems that were explainable and ran extremely unstable. Often when programmers jailbreak these programs to run without iLok security they delete necessary code to do so, in turn causing changes to the program itself often unnoticed by the programmers initially.

It's possible your torrent may have been corrupted during download.

I'ts possible the program is dated at this point however unlikely.

My advice would be to obtain either a legit version of Cubase 5 or just try getting another more recent build of the program e.g. 5.12 or something similar.

The value to owning a legit version of the program is that you can go directly to the Steinberg website and get any recent updates often containing bug fixes. It is also possible that your settings are adjusted incorrectly. I'm sure there are hundreds of youtube vids on how to correct any feedback loops or clashing input sources.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to devices -> Device setup -> VST Audio system. What ASIO are you currently using within the program? Whats the latency? Does the problem go away if you change the ASIO used?